# unfortunately App has Stopped- Passing Intent data between two Activites

Tags: java, android-intent, android-studio, radio-button

I am trying to pass String data using intent from Authorites.class to Issues.class .  When a radio button is chosen and button is clicked, 1st activity has to show toast as well as pass the Radio button value to next activity. 
When i choose the radio-button and press the button in Authorites.class,the app stops and exits. Plz find where have i gone wrong

```
 public class Authorities extends AppCompatActivity {

 /**
 * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
 * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
 */
//private GoogleApiClient client;
 RadioButton auth_button;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authorities);
    final RadioGroup auth_grp = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgrp);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.authselect);

    button1.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        // store the text corresponding to  the RadioButton which is clicke
        int sa = auth_grp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        auth_button = (RadioButton) findViewById(sa);
    //           String auth=auth_button.getText().toString();
         Toast.makeText(Authorities.this, auth_button.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent i;
        i=new Intent(Authorities.this, Issues.class);
   //            Intent i = new       Intent().setClassName("com.example.chethan.wapp.Authorities", "com.example.chethan.wapp.Issues");
  //            i.putExtra("Auth",auth);
  // Starts TargetActivity
  //            Authorities.this.startActivity(i);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    });
 }
```

Issues.class should recieve the Intent data returned from previous activity

```
 public class Issues extends AppCompatActivity {
CheckBox mws,sl,swc,sws,dr;
Button b2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //  mws=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.mws);
 //   sl=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sl);
  //  swc=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.swc);
 //   sws=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sws);
 //   dr=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.dr);

    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nxt);
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String value1 = extras.getString("Auth");

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Authority you chose is:\n"+value1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Here's the log cat:

**02-29 10:54:00.594 1960-1960/com.example.chethan.wapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.example.chethan.wapp, PID: 1960
                                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.chethan.wapp/com.example.chethan.wapp.Issues}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.example.chethan.wapp.Issues.onCreate(Issues.java:34)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**

Comment: can we see your logcat??

Comment: which is line 30 in Issues class ?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are getting string value1 data from getString("Auth") of Intent in Issues class but in Authorities class you are not putting any ("Auth") value in Intent obj.
So uncomment this line...

```
           i.putExtra("Auth",auth);
```

then run the project...

Comment: I've tried what you instructed which still leaves me with the same problem. "unfortunately App stopped".. But still thank u for ur response